# Class "App\Models\BlogPostCategory" not found in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8

After creating a new post, I want it to redirect the page to a list of the posts. It is creating it successfully, and data insert into the database correctly, but when it redirects, I got this error, and the same class is working in authors functions in the same controller.

**BlogController**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Backend;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Blog\BlogPostCategory;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Models\BlogPost;
use Image;

class BlogController extends Controller
{
    public function BlogPostStore(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'post_title_en' => 'required',
            'post_title_ar' => 'required',
            'post_image' => 'required',
        ], [
            'post_title_en.required' => 'Input Post Title English Name',
            'post_title_ar.required' => 'Input Post Title Arabic Name',
        ]);

        $image = $request->file('post_image');
        $name_gen = hexdec(uniqid()).'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        Image::make($image)->resize(780, 433)->save('upload/post/'.$name_gen);
        $save_url = 'upload/post/'.$name_gen;

        BlogPost::insert([
            'category_id' => $request->category_id,
            'post_title_en' => $request->post_title_en,
            'post_title_ar' => $request->post_title_ar,
            'post_slug_en' => strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $request->post_title_en)),
            'post_slug_ar' => str_replace(' ', '-', $request->post_title_ar),
            'post_image' => $save_url,
            'post_details_en' => $request->post_details_en,
            'post_details_ar' => $request->post_details_ar,
            'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
        ]);

        $notification = array(
            'message' => 'Blog Post Inserted Successfully',
            'alert-type' => 'success'
        );

        return redirect()->route('list.post')->with($notification);
    }
}
```

*Pposts list function in BlogController**

```
public function ListBlogPost()
{
    $blogpost = BlogPost::with('category')->latest()->get();
    
    return view('backend.blog.post.post_list', compact('blogpost'));
}
```

**Routes**

```
Route::prefix('blog')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/list/post', [BlogController::class, 'ListBlogPost'])
        ->name('list.post');
    Route::post('/post/store', [BlogController::class, 'BlogPostStore'])
        ->name('post-store');
});
```

**and I create BlogPostCategory class in path**

```
App\Models\Blog\BlogPostCategory;
```

Comment: Can you update your question by including the contents of `App\Models\BlogPost`? Cheers

Comment: Try cleaning cache

Comment: I believe the issue is that the `category` method within the `App\Models\BlogPost` model has a relationship configured (`BelongsTo`, `HasOne`, `HasMany` etc...) that points to `App\Models\BlogPostCategory` instead of `App\Models\Blog\BlogPostCategory`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is most likely due to the relationship definition within the `App\Models\BlogPost` model.

I think you have a `category` method in your `App\Models\BlogPost` model;

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(BlogPostCategory::class);
}
```

So it is looking for `BlogPostCategory` in same namespace but since your `BlogPostCategory` 's full path is `App\Models\Blog\BlogPostCategory` you need to specify this.

Add `use App\Models\Blog\BlogPostCategory;` on top of your `App\Models\BlogPost` class.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Blog\BlogPostCategory;
//    other classes

class BlogPost extends Model
{
    // other stuff

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(BlogPostCategory::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@ALAA ELDIN, There would be one of the below errors. -

1. Check out the importing path you have used in BlogPost. Check the association as well.
2. Check out the importing path you have used in the BlogPostCategory model.

Just rectify the path & clear the cache, and the error will be resolved.